# Showing pointwise $\mathbb C$-linearity of a $1$-form $\omega$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, connections

I'm currently working on a problem in the context of the trivial complex vector bundle $\mathbb CP^n\times \mathbb C^{n+1}$ where at one point I am supposed to verify that the connection $1$-form $\omega$ of its respective connection $\nabla$ is pointwise $\mathbb C$-linear.

The respective connection form is defined as $$\omega = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\overline{z}_kdz_k}{1+\Vert z\Vert^2}$$

Now (pointwise) $\omega$ being a $1$-form means we consider $$\omega\colon T_{[1,z]}\mathbb CP^n\to \mathbb C$$
So it should suffice to verify that $$\omega(\lambda X_{[1,z]}) = \lambda\omega(X_{[1,z]}),\quad \lambda \in \mathbb C,\ X_{[1,z]} \in T_{[1,z]}\mathbb CP^n $$

But I am uncertain what $\omega(X_{[1,z]})$ evaluates to. I am still not feeling very comfortable working with these objects, e.g. connection forms etc. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure the point isn’t $[1,z]$?

Comment: Hello Ted Shifrin, that makes sense, yes. Thanks for that, I'll edit my question.

Comment: You’re working in one of the standard coordinate charts, so there’s nothing mysterious. But this looks more like a connection form on a line bundle.

Comment: Yes, the problem I'm working on is about a connection on a line bundle. Sorry, wasn't sure whether this would matter. My apologies. Assuming $X_{[1,z]}$ would be a tangent vector, how would $\omega(X_{[1,z]})$ look like?

Comment: $\omega$ is a $(1,0)$-form. Write your (complexified) tangent vector as linear combination of  $\partial/\partial z_j$ and their conjugates. Review basic manifold stuff and complex manifold stuff.

Comment: That helps, thanks for the hint Ted! Highly appreciated.